# Sunspot + Sidekiq (sunspot-queue gem) Have to restart Solr every time after create or update data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot, sidekiq

When I created a record from rails console, it doesn't show up in the result until I restart the solr server.

My Sunspot.yml
https://gist.github.com/jianbo/6264610

My log/sunspot-solr-development.log
https://gist.github.com/jianbo/6264600

I have put auto_commit_after_request: true into my sunspot.yml, but this still result: INFO: commitTracker AutoCommit: disabled in line 142. Not sure if this is the problem...

When the data was save, I can see the something has been added to Redis server
https://gist.github.com/jianbo/6264594

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding auto commit:

```
<autoCommit> 
  <maxDocs>10000</maxDocs>
  <maxTime>20000</maxTime>
</autoCommit>
```